# Can I trigger pre-loading of modules when using ui-router lazy loading

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, lazy-loading

I'm using Angular8 with UI-Router.

Some of my modules are lazy-loaded using UI-Router Future States

```js
export const futureState = {
    name: "app.users.**",
    url: "/users",
    loadChildren: () => import("../user.module").then((m) => m.UserModule)
};
```

Browsing to `/users` causes the UserModule to be fetched over the network and loaded. (as part of a file produced by WebPack)

Is it possible for the initial page to trigger the lazy-load the UserModule, so that when `/users` is visited the UserModule has already been loaded?

Comment: there is preloading strategy option for such cases in native AngularRouterModule, but you have to switch from UI router

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work:

```js
export class HomePageComponent implements OnInit {

    ngOnInit() {
        //Preload the user pages here as it's likely the user will
        //visit them next
        import("./user/user.module").then(m => m.UserModule);
    }
}
```

I've left the future state definition as above. This causes the UserModule to be loaded:

- If the user visits the home page
- If the user goes directly to the user page